# T-SQL XQuery nested namespace issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, namespaces, xquery

I just want an actualEndTime - is that so much to ask?

```
declare @x xml = '
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <bogus>1934</bogus>
    <getJobActionsResponse xmlns="urn:JobService">
      <getJobActionsReturn>
        <job xmlns:ns1="urn:JobService" xsi:type="ns1:SvcJob">
          <actions />
          <actualEndTime>
            <dateString>2019-05-15 19:46:54.207</dateString>
          </actualEndTime>
        </job>
      </getJobActionsReturn>
    </getJobActionsResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'
```

It seems from posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056208/how-to-use-xquery-t-sql-to-parse-customer-xml-that-contains-nested-default-names) that I should be able to do a query like this:

```
;with xmlnamespaces (N'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as ns0, 
                     N'urn:JobService' as ns2)
select @x.value('(/ns0:envelope/ns0:body/ns2:getJobActions/ns2:getJobActionsReturn/ns2:job/ns2:actualEndTime)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

I've tried various permutations of namespace prefixing, but everything I try returns null. I can't even get an upstream bogus value to return non-null:

```
;with xmlnamespaces (N'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as ns0)
select @x.value('(/ns0:envelope/ns0:body/ns0:bogus)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

I don't get namespaces (every web page explaining them seems to be a mile long). Sorry, please and thanks.

Comment: The answer by marc_s is great and the way you should walk (in terms of *"Be as specific as possible!"*, but there is an *easy-cheesy* approach too: `SELECT @x.value('(//*:actualEndTime/*:dateString/text())[1]','datetime')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but you had these mistakes:

- Tag names are **case-sensitive** - you need to use `<ns0:Envelope>` (not `<ns0:envelope>`) etc.
- You misspelled the `<ns2:getJobActionsResponse>` as `<ns2:getJobActions>`
- You didn't go "all the way down" to the `<ns2:dateString>` element

Try this :

```
declare @x xml = '
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <bogus>1934</bogus>
    <getJobActionsResponse xmlns="urn:JobService">
      <getJobActionsReturn>
        <job xmlns:ns1="urn:JobService" xsi:type="ns1:SvcJob">
          <actions />
          <actualEndTime>
            <dateString>2019-05-15 19:46:54.207</dateString>
          </actualEndTime>
        </job>
      </getJobActionsReturn>
    </getJobActionsResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'

;with xmlnamespaces (N'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as ns0, 
                     N'urn:JobService' as ns2)
select @x.value('(/ns0:Envelope/ns0:Body/ns2:getJobActionsResponse/ns2:getJobActionsReturn/ns2:job/ns2:actualEndTime/ns2:dateString)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

Comment: Ooo! Awesome. Now, what is with the odd fact that if I omit "/ns2:dateString", it still works?

Comment: @bwperrin: that's because the `<ns2:actualEndTime>` node really only has one single child node with a value - so asking for the `<ns2:actualEndTime>` will return the inner child node's value - but that's just a bit "shaky" - don't rely on something like that - **be explicit and complete/accurate!**